# Как работает рекурсивный setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Прошу объяснить как работает рекурсивный setTimeout, почему в стеке не сохраняется контекст предыдущих вызовов, как в обычной рекурсивной функции ?

например тут:

```
var i = 1;
setTimeout(function run() {
  func(i);
  setTimeout(run, 100);
}, 100);
```

Comment: Подробнее расскажите, не понятно, что не так. Переменная с функцией передаются:
https://jsfiddle.net/e9L63mp1/

Comment: Приведите пример, ожидание и реальность.

Comment: потому что на самом деле это не совсем рекурсия,

Comment: у меня ваш пример отработал, без вызова `func` разумеется т.к вы не предоставили данную функцию

Comment: Рекурсии в вашем примере нет, есть только планирование вызова через 100мс. Т.е. ваш код выполняется сразу, а через 100мс движок js вызвет обработчик.

Answer (score 3):

Пример рекурсии с `setTimeout`

```js
(function loops(){
   setTimeout(function(){
       console.log('test');
       loops(); // рекурсия
   }, 1000);
})();
```

Демо
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/revEqd?editors=1111

Comment: на самом деле это не рекурсия